# Two strings are not exact in Excel until F2-Enter

Tags: excel, vba

I have two strings below.

```
|-
          "For PayPal payments, %{service_name} charges a commission of %{paypal_commission}%. PayPal's fees are not included in this commission, so in addition to %{service_name} commission, you also need to pay PayPal's fees from each payment processed by PayPal. PayPal's fee is between 2% and 5% of the total sales price, depending on your monthly sales volume and the country of residence of the buyer. In general, domestic purchases have lower fees than international ones, and higher monthly sales give you a discount on fees.
          You can see the exact fees by logging in to your PayPal account and going %{link_to_paypal}. After each purchase you will get a receipt displaying the exact fee."
```

```
|-
          "For PayPal payments, %{service_name} charges a commission of %{paypal_commission}%. PayPal's fees are not included in this commission, so in addition to %{service_name} commission, you also need to pay PayPal's fees from each payment processed by PayPal. PayPal's fee is between 2% and 5% of the total sales price, depending on your monthly sales volume and the country of residence of the buyer. In general, domestic purchases have lower fees than international ones, and higher monthly sales give you a discount on fees.
          You can see the exact fees by logging in to your PayPal account and going %{link_to_paypal}. After each purchase you will get a receipt displaying the exact fee."
```

Using Exact() function in Excel shows that the 2 strings are not the same.

However if I click F2-Enter on the first string, then the Exact() function returns TRUE.

If I undo and click F2-Enter on the second string, the Exact() function remains FALSE.

If I F2 and copy the content of the cells to two other cells, the Exact() function evaluates to TRUE.

The first string is generated using VBA pulling data from a .yml text file (ADODB command). The second string is generated using Power Query pulling from a .csv file

I need these strings to be the same without any intervention. First, I need to check why are the content different?

Comment: have you tried nesting `TRIM` call inside `EXACT`? I guess this might be due to some invisible control characters towards the end of the strings.

Comment: I tested above input strings by copying them (including the double quotes) but I am not able to reproduce the issue i.e. `EXACT` function returns `TRUE` irrespective of `F2` and `ENTER` keys. I'd suggest checking `LEN` of both results and then comparing them character by character using VBA.

Comment: If F2+Enter is formatting strings as text then it means the first string has some hidden notation and its format isn't Text, it'll be something else, maybe showing as "custom"?, which is why applying F2+ENTER makes `EXACT()=TRUE`. The 2nd string is already text so nothing changes. If string 1 and 2 are in cells A1 and A2, then try in VBA `.Range("A1").value2 = .Range("A1").value2"` - this works for me with numbers that come in as text. Using `.Value2` gets rid of boxing like date formats etc.